# Is there a way to break open this coal door?

Tags: stardew-valley

Is there a way to break open this door?

[image]

Comment: I imagine it is there purely for aesthetic reasons. The mines have supposedly been abandoned for a while iirc, so that door is probably just signs of a cave-in.

Comment: It looks really conspicuous though...

Comment: I think the question is more about getting the coal than using the passage to traverse the mines. There's several other instances of coal being kept in places that you can access down there (dropped bag, mine cart full of coal, ..). Seeing as you can interact with and collect these, there should be a way to get the coal behind that door.

Answer (score 5):

No, that door is purely there for aesthetic reasons. In the game, we find that the mines have been abandoned for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The ladders and elevator are currently the only way to get around in the mines.